# $\pi_1(M)=\langle a,b|b^{-1} b^{-1},a \rangle \cong \Bbb Z?$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

$\pi_1(M)=\langle a,b|b^{-1} b^{-1},a \rangle \cong \Bbb Z?$ Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the relations do you mean that $a=1$ and $b^{-1}b^{-1}=1$? In which case of course not. The fact that $a=1$ means $$\left<a,b|b^{-1}b^{-1},a\right>=\left<b|b^{-1}b^{-1}\right>=\left<b|b^{2}\right>.$$
But $\mathbb{Z}$ is free, so it cannot equal a group on one generator with relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's $\Bbb Z_2$, since $a=e$.

Comment: Would you please tell me why Z2?

Comment: Since $b^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-2}=e,$ we have $b^2=e$, @Christian. Map $$b\mapsto [1]_2$$ and $$e\mapsto [0]_2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Which book do you recommend me to learn more about this kind of topic?

Comment: Well, if you want an almost encyclopedic treatment, you can't go far wrong with Magnus *et al.*'s *"Combinatorial Group Theory,"* although that might be a bit advanced, since you're struggling on this. Most textbooks on group theory explain the calculus of presentations in their advanced sections though, @Christian.

Comment: I appreciate your time sir.

Comment: You're welcome, @Christian. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).